# apache mod rewrite url with htaccess syntax

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to rewrite this url `www.example.com/test1/aaa/bbb/?ccc=123` to `www.example.com/test2?x=aaa&y=bbb&ccc=123`

I used this rewrite rule
`RewriteRule test1/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?(.*) /test2?x=$1&y=$2&$3 [L]`

but it failed to work for the last parameter. What should it be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. Use it this way using `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule test1/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /test2?x=$1&y=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.